# Flask - can not load proper 'current_user'

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a User and Organizer, both who can login
i have provided a account page, whose function has a @login_required decorator

```
@app.route("/account", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def account():
    if current_user.user_type == 'user':
        form = UpdateAccountForm_User()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            current_user.username = form.username.data
            current_user.email = form.email.data
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Your account has been updated!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('account'))
        image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.image_file)
        return render_template('account.html', title='Account', image_file=image_file, form=form)
    
    elif current_user.user_type == 'organizer':
        form = UpdateAccountForm_Organizer()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            current_user.org_name = form.org_name.data
            current_user.org_email = form.org_email.data
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Your account has been updated!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('account'))
        image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.image_file)
        return render_template('account.html', title='Account', image_file=image_file, form=form)
```

Now, no matter whome i am logged in with, the current_user always holds the User model information

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
        {% if current_user.__tablename__ == 'organizer'%}
        <div class="content-section">
            <div class="media">
              <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ image_file }}">
              <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="account-heading">{{ current_user.org_name }}</h2>
                <p class="text-secondary">{{ current_user.org_email }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
              <form method="POST" action="">
                  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                  <fieldset class="form-group">
                      <legend class="p-2 bg-blur bg-gradient transition rounded">Account Info</legend>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}
      
                          {% if form.username.errors %}
                              {{ form.username( class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid", placeholder="Username") }}
                              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                  {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                                      <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                  {% endfor %}
                              </div>
                          {% else %}
                              {{ form.username( class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid", placeholder="Username") }}
                          {% endif %}                    
                      </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
      
                              {% if form.email.errors %}
                                  {{ form.email( class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid", placeholder="email") }}
                                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                      {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                                          <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                      {% endfor %}
                                  </div>
                              {% else %}
                                  {{ form.email( class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid", placeholder="email") }}
                              {% endif %}      
                          </div>
                  </fieldset>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
                  </div>
                </form>
          </div>
          {% elif current_user.__tablename__ == 'user' %}
          <div class="content-section">
            <div class="media">
              <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ image_file }}">
              <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="account-heading">{{ current_user.username }}</h2>
                <p class="text-secondary">{{ current_user.email }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
              <form method="POST" action="">
                  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                  <fieldset class="form-group">
                      <legend class="p-2 bg-blur bg-gradient transition rounded">Account Info</legend>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}
      
                          {% if form.username.errors %}
                              {{ form.username( class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid", placeholder="Username") }}
                              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                  {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                                      <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                  {% endfor %}
                              </div>
                          {% else %}
                              {{ form.username( class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid", placeholder="Username") }}
                          {% endif %}                    
                      </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
      
                              {% if form.email.errors %}
                                  {{ form.email( class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid", placeholder="email") }}
                                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                      {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                                          <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                      {% endfor %}
                                  </div>
                              {% else %}
                                  {{ form.email( class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid", placeholder="email") }}
                              {% endif %}      
                          </div>
                  </fieldset>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
                  </div>
                </form>
          </div>
        {% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

How can i ensure that when logging in using Organizer credentials, the 'current_user' is of type organizer

can this be the problem?

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    # Check if the user ID corresponds to a User or an Organizer
    user = User.query.get(int(user_id))
    if user:
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))
    organizer = Organizer.query.get(int(user_id))
    if organizer:
        return Organizer.query.get(int(user_id))
    return None
```

[image: I am currently logged in as a organizer, but in the top right corner you can see the current_user is of type user]

I am currently logged in as a organizer, but in the top right corner you can see the current_user is of type user